# How do I mock Audio API in Jest properly?

Tags: jestjs

I'm writing a test that needs to simulate and provide accessor facilities for validating my Audio implementation is correct. I successfully implemented my setup method like so:

```js
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import { AudioState } from '../src';

export class MockAudio extends Audio {
  src: string;
  state: AudioState;
  duration: number;
  playing: boolean;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.playing = false;
    this.duration = NaN;
    this.state = AudioState.STOPPED;
    this.src = '';
  }
  fastSeek = (time: number): Promise<void> => {
    this.currentTime = time;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  play = (): Promise<void> => {
    this.playing = true;
    this.state = AudioState.PLAYING;
    return super.play();
  }
  pause = (): void => {
    this.playing = false;
    this.state = AudioState.PAUSED;
    return super.pause();
  }
}

HTMLMediaElement.prototype.pause = () => Promise.resolve();
HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play = () => Promise.resolve();

window.Audio = MockAudio;

Object.defineProperty(window, 'MediaSource', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((params) => ({
    // MediaSource implementation goes here
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

As you can see I'm setting the methods up so that they can effect the object properties in a way that simulates the Audio API. I'm wondering how I can do this properly with mockImplementation and defineProperty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem (or mocking any other inbuild API classes) using what is described here: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock

What I like to do is to first define my mocks for later use in a `test-utils.js` like this:

```js
export const mocks = {
  Audio: {
    pause: jest.fn(),
    play: jest.fn(),
  },
}
```

Now I mock the actual class in my `jest.setup.js` (as defined in the jest config):

```js
import { mocks } from "./test-utils"

// Audio mock
global.Audio = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  pause: mocks.Audio.pause,
  play: mocks.Audio.play,
}))
```

and finally I can expect against the mocks in my test:

```js
import { mocks } from "./test-utils"

describe("Something", () => {
  it("should work", () => {
    // run your test here
    expect(mocks.Audio.pause).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

of course remember to clean up the mocks as needed.

And the relevant part of the jest config in my `package.json` to trigger the setup file:

```
  "jest": {
    ...,
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! none questions helped me. this works and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Audio.play()` returns a Promise: `HTMLMediaElement.play(): Promise<void>`

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

This worked best for me using Typescript

```
global.Audio = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  pause: jest.fn(),
  play: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about play returning Promise. However, i still needed mocks in order to see if method was called. Crazy thing, this doesn't work:

```
export const mocks = {
  Audio: {
    pause: jest.fn(),
    play: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  },
}
```

The code breaks saying that in `file.play().catch(...)` returns: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`

Somehow returned promise gets lost and play method always returns `undefined`. I tried all possible jest APIs and everything gives result. But this works `play: () => Promise.resolve()` but then i cannot test if it was called or not...