# Mock audio player events with Jest

Tags: typescript, audio, jestjs, mocking, jsdom

I'm trying to test my own audio player (based in an **html audio element**) however I've been unable to mock the emission of events ([onended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event), onerror, etc).

Is there a way of mocking these events using jest?

The "regular" methods are already being mocked, as well as the events are being handled. However the events are not emitted (mocked).

Has anybody achieved something similar?

PS: I'm using typescript

[Update]

I'm copying an [existing snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591847/how-do-i-mock-audio-api-in-jest-properly), this is it:

```js
export const mocks = {
  Audio: {
    pause: jest.fn(),
    play: jest.fn()
    // onended: --> this is the event I'd like to know how to invoke/mock
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: updated @jonrsharpe, sorry about that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same situation, and saw the same links you did, but I managed to solve it using spyOn.

I set up the mock:

```
const mockAudio = jest
  .spyOn(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'play')
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())
```

And then expected it:

```
expect(mockAudio).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I confirmed it worked by commenting out the audio.play() in the code being tested and the test passed/failed appropriately.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ended implementing a mock player and simulate the call to onended, onemptied, oncanplay and oncanplaythrough (and resolving the play method). I needed to listen to the play promise and the onended event at the same time.